# Unable to access props values in data method in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the code (vuejs2) -

```
Vue.component('competetion-list', {
  template: `<div>{{totalCompetetions}}</div>`,
  props: ['values'],
  data: function () {
    return { totalCompetetions: this.values.length}
  }
})
```

Nothing is printed on the page but if I change the `template` value to

```
template: `<div>{{this.values.length}}</div>`
```

it prints `15`. What am I doing wrong and how can I pass the `props` to the `data`?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: At the time of initialization, prop may or may not contain the valid data, watch for changes in the prop and update it accordingly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was unable to assign the prop `values` to data `totalCompetetions` in the following way -

```
data: function () {
    return { totalCompetetions: this.values.length}
  }
```

---

But I was able to do it using the `watch`, `computed`, and `methods` properties.

**With `watch` property -**

```
  watch: {
    values: function(){
      this.totalCompetitions = this.values;
    }
  }
```

**With `computed` property -**

```
 computed:{
    competition:{
      get: function(){
        return this.values.length;
      }
    }
```

**With `methods` property -**

```
 methods:{
    competitionn: function(){
      return this.values.length;
    }
  }
```

---

But for `computed` and `methods` properties, I needed to set `totalCompetetions` in the following way -

**For `computed` -**

```
template: `<div><p>{{totalCompetitions = competition}}</p></div>` //without parenthesis
```

**For `methods` -**

```
template: `<div><p>{{totalCompetitions = competition()}}</p></div>` //with parenthesis
```

Answer (score 4):

**You code does work**.

I guess the problem is your parent component. Did you pass the `values` correctly? for example:

```
<competetion-list :values="[1, 2, 3]"></competetion-list>
```

Besides, for your case I'd say computed properties is a better solution.

```
computed: {
  totalCompetetions () {
    return this.values.length
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the data() method, you should be able to reference the component's properties using `this`.

Try following:

```
Vue.component('competetion-list', {
  template: `<div>{{totalCompetetions}}</div>`,
  props: ['values'],
  data: function () {
    var data = { totalCompetetions: this.values.length}
    return data
  }
})
```

As validly mentioned in the comment, if `values` array is changing later, you may have to put a watcher on the prop and inside watcher, set `totalCompetetions` as `this.values.length`.